# Making empty string to have 0 value in MySQL without using trigger

Tags: mysql

My Query for today is that I wanted to set my MySQL value to zero whenever an empty string is saved. Is there a way to do this without using trigger? What I wanted is like this in the illustration

```
          TABLE DATA                                   MYSQL TABLE VALUE
name    age    years of experience      -->            name    age    yrs
John    23                              -->            John    23      0
```

Comment: set the default value to `0` for that field

Comment: Already did, but stil no luck

Comment: use the default + an update script running the `IFNULL()` example from the answer to correct already existing entires in your db

Answer (score 1):

Set the field to stay **NULL** if hs no value

```
ALTER DATA MODIFY years_of_experience varchar(255) null;
```

And try this:

```
select name,age,IFNULL(years_of_experience,0) from DATA;
```